# creating a UI in background thread WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I tried following:

```
var task = new Task(() =>
    {
       for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
          //Create new Grid HERE
          // Add Table with some dynamic data here..
          // print the above Grid here.
        }

    });

task.ContinueWith((previousTask) =>
    {
        label.Content = printerStatus(); // will return "Out of Paper", "printing", "Paper jam", etc.
    },
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

label.Content = "Sending to printer";
```

It returns following error: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this..

The error occurs when it tries to create a new UI object Grid.

How can i fix this?  Let me know if there is any other way arround!

Answer (score 2):

Tasks use thread pool threads, which are in a MTA.

If you want a background STA thread, you will have to create one yourself and explicitly set the `ApartmentState`.

```
Thread t = new Thread( ... );
t.SetApartmentState( ApartmentState.STA );
t.Start();
```

Comment: can you show me the sample code. I am very new to this technology.

Comment: And how can i know the task is complete using this?

Comment: I suggest reading [Joe Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) for the basics. You have to use Threads not Tasks if you want an STA, so you don't have `ContinueWith`. You will have to use `Dispatcher.Invoke` from inside your thread method instead.

Comment: @user995387 - Unless you report the progress of the thread, you have no way of knowing when the thread will be completed, thats entirely up the the scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create UI objects on different thread than the main UI thread because as soon as you add them to the UI, it tries to set the `Parent` property, and a thread in WPF cannot modify objects that were created on a different thread.

Instead, I'd recommend creating a list or collection of the Grid's Data on the 2nd thread, and binding it to the UI using something like an `ItemsControl`. This will keep all UI objects on the main UI thread, while background processing can be done on a background thread.

To update a UI object from a background thread, such as your status label, I'd recommend using the `Dispatcher` like [lawrencealan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8667575/302677) suggests. The `Dispatcher` is WPF's internal message queue for the main UI thread

Comment: possible to add any examples for this?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Dispatcher for the label and Invoke might help:

```
label.Dispatcher.Invoke(
      System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
      new Action(
        delegate()
        {
          label.Content = printerStatus();
        }
    ));
```

Comment: It is not able to create Grid! it shows error in Grid object whlie creating it.

Comment: What do you mean by grid, you mean DataGridView or Simple Grid data structure.

Comment: WPF Grid. that holds the UI contents..msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx

Comment: When modifying any sort of UI objects that are not created in the same thread, from within another thread or background worker, you need to use a Dispatcher.

I think maybe your Grid creation is another problem, unless you are attempting to modify an existing UI object.

Comment: here is what i wanted to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671277/correct-method-of-threading